# Type mismatch, cannot convert from void to char[]

Tags: java, type-mismatch

I'm testing if 2 strings are anagrams. I figured that if I make them arrays then sort them, and they turn out to be equal, they are anagrams. I'm having a type mismatch compiler error though, and I cannot figure out why.

```
package local.random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "go hang a salami";
        String s2 = "im a lasagna hog";

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);

        System.out.println(IsAnagram(s1,s2));   
    }

    public static boolean IsAnagram (String s1, String s2)
    {   
        char[] s1Char = s1.toCharArray();
        char[] s2Char = s2.toCharArray();

        char[] s1Sorted = Arrays.sort(s1Char);//Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to char[]
        char[] s2Sorted = Arrays.sort(s2Char);

        System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + s1.toString());
        System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + s2.toString());

        if (s1Sorted.equals(s2Sorted)){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Anagram []";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort` return type is void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.sort()` does not return an array. Instead, it modifies the contents of the array, just remove the `char[] s1Sorted =` and `char[] s2Sorted =` parts. Also, use `Arrays.equals()` to compare arrays, and your `System.out.println()` statements print the strings, not the array. To convert an array to a string, do `Arrays.deepToString`, or if you just want a string representation of the char array, do `new String(param)`, where param is the char array.

Comment: Thank you, it all works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the corrected code . 
sort takes Array as reference it doesnt return anything. 
Array comparison can be done by `Array.equals`

```
public class Anagram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "go hang a salami";
    String s2 = "im a lasagna hog";

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);

    System.out.println(IsAnagram(s1, s2));

}

public static boolean IsAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] s1Char = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] s2Char = s2.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(s1Char);//Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to char[]
    Arrays.sort(s2Char);
   //need to construct a new String to print.
    System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + new String(s1Char));
    System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + new String(s2Char));

    return Arrays.equals(s1Char, s2Char);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Anagram []";
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the corrected code. The `System.out.println` statements do not output the intended result.

Comment: yes true . I didnt pay attention to that printing statement.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort` is a `void` method because it works by changing the array you passed to it.

Also, sorting the array you get from `toCharArray` will not sort the characters in the original string. `String` is immutable (cannot be changed), so `toCharArray` returns a *new* array.

The correct way to sort the characters of a string is this.

```
String string = "SPOILAGE";
char[] arr = string.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(arr);
String word = new String(arr);
System.out.println(word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put these two lines :

`Arrays.sort(s1Char);`
`Arrays.sort(s2Char);`

It will automatically sort these char arrays. No need to re assign it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort(char[]) is a method that returns void.
Change your method to:

```
public static boolean IsAnagram (String s1, String s2)
{   
    char[] s1Char = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] s2Char = s2.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(s1Char);
    Arrays.sort(s2Char);

    char[] s1Sorted = s1Char;
    char[] s2Sorted = s2Char;

    System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + s1.toString());
    System.out.println("The first string sorted alphabetically is :" + s2.toString());

    if (s1Sorted.equals(s2Sorted)){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```