# Whats wrong with the following code

Tags: java, arrays, to-char

Why isn't the following code working ?

```
String s = "fecbda";
Arrays.sort(s.toCharArray());
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36510808/3973077

Comment: What is wrong about it? please use a proper title for your question (more specific than that)

Comment: "*Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must **include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*" - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable so you can't change them, and you shouldn't expect this to do anything.

What you might have intended is

```
String s = "fecbda"; 
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars); 
String s2 = new String(chars);
System.out.println(s2);
```

Comment: You can print `chars` directly. No need to create `s2`.

Comment: For a complete answer, quote javadoc of [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29): *Returns a **newly allocated** character array*

Comment: @Andreas You can't use `System.out.println(chars)` but you can do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars))` which I suspect is not what the OP expected.

Comment: Yeah you can. See [`PrintStream.println(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char[]%29)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work as [`s.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--):

> Returns:
>       a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

The operative part of the documentation is that it creates a **new** array (i.e. a copy of the characters in the string) and when you sort that array you do not sort the String.

You cannot sort the string as it is immutable but you can make a new string out of the sorted character array like this:

```
String s = "fecbda";
char[] c = s.toCharArray();
Array.sort( c );
String n = new String( c );
```

As an alternative method, you can do it in Java 8 using streams:

```
String s = "fecbda";

String n = s.chars()  // Convert to an IntStream of character codes
            .sorted() // Sort
            .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((char) i)) // Convert to strings
            .collect(Collectors.joining()); // Concatenate the strings.
```